# How do I tell the difference between a positional parameter and a parameter that needs words before it

Tags: google-drive-api

I saw this in the documentation for Google Drive
[image]

If I'm not a computer science expert, how am I to know that I need to do list(fileId="string") and not list("string")
and how was I to guess that there would be a .execute() thingy after it to get the goods?  Do you learn it in college or is there some other documentation on drive api basics or some course that professionals all know.  I'm not trying to be facetious.  It just seems really inaccessible if you're not a real programmer as if only real programmers should try this stuff.  In the future, where would I look to find these methods or how would I understand the way these parameters are to be passed into these functions?

Here's an additional picture of what I mean.  It seems to be the case that other believe as do I that if there are no equal sign with a default in the signature, then it is eligible for positional parameter treatment.

[image: I was wrong]

I was wrong and if you believe that, either you or google is wrong.  I'm no programmer.  I think I"m wrong.  So how do I tell the difference between a positional parameter and one I can refer to with words like I would in visual basic.?
[image: still wrong but for other reason]

Answer (score 0):

### When you want to implement a Google API method, the first thing your should do is to consult the [method reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list)

- This documentation shows you which parameters exist, what they are good for, which of them are required and which are optional
- There is also a `Try this API` functionality you can use for testing
- The `Try this API` has fields and values for the parameters
- Once you found the right request syntax for the `Try this API` that executes  in the desired way, you can transform the request into your language of choice
- The [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) gives you an idea of how to translate your request into Python
- The documentation linked under [Further reading](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) redirects you to the [Drive API PyDoc documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.comments.html) that  gives you specific information for each method
- As a rule of thumb: The required parameters (in you case the `fileId`)  can be specified as "string" instead of fileId="string" (because the method expects you to provide it), while the optional parameters have to be preceded by the field name in order to avoid ambiguity
- Otherwise, if you just specify "None" - how would the method know if this means `pageSize=None` or `pageToken=None`?
- It is never wrong to precede all parameters (included the required ones) with their field name, especially if you indicate them in a non-standard order (e.g. if `filedId` is not the first parameter)
- `execute()` needs to be used for all Google API methods in Python to indicate that you finished assigning all parameters to your request and now want to actually execute it.